# How do i reflectively create an instance of enum in golang?

Tags: go

I'm trying to create an instance of enum from its reflect.Type and value
https://play.golang.org/p/PqklMe_Z4WX

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)
type WeekDay string
const (
    SUNDAY WeekDay = "sunday"
    MONDAY WeekDay = "monday"
)
func (day WeekDay) WeekDay() bool {
    switch day {
    case SUNDAY, MONDAY:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func main() {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(WeekDay("sunday"))
    x := reflect.New(rt)
    x = x.Elem()
    x.Set(reflect.ValueOf("sunday"))
    fmt.Println(x.Interface())
}
```

Is there a way to create an instance of enum in golang with its type and possible value of constant?

Comment: The playground link is good, but please include the code in the question.

Comment: Change line 25 to x.Set(reflect.ValueOf(WeekDay("sunday")) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reflect.New(t).Elem()` to get a value and [`SetString`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.SetString) to set the value.

```
// t is the reflect.Type for a Weekday
t := reflect.TypeOf(WeekDay("sunday"))

// v is reflect.Value for a WeekDay, initialized to the zero value ""
v := reflect.New(t).Elem()

// Set the value of v to "sunday"
v.SetString("sunday")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qvoVIN2Ro7x